# Cocoa webview windowScriptObject keeping strong reference

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In my NSViewController i use a web view, which calls the methods of the viewcontroller

The view controller registers itself for a key in windowScriptObject

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didClearWindowObject:(WebScriptObject *)windowScriptObject forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    [windowScriptObject setValue:self forKey:@"CocoaApp"];
}
```

**The problem is, the windowScriptObject retains (keeps strong ref) the value and my VC never deallocs
How to avoid this (best without moving the code logic to an additional object)?**

(i believe thats the same situation with iOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your cleanup code (for example `windowWillClose:`, call this:

```
[self.webView close];
```

The above will clear the window script object and release the reference to your view controller.

Comment: nice point with the close method, i did solved it however with a 3.th object, which keeps weak reference to NSViewController, but strong to the script object

Comment: You'll leak the 3rd object, but that might not be as big of an issue as leaking the view controller. Calling `close` will take care of this. Would you mind marking this as the correct answer?